# closing questions seems contradictory in some cases

Tags: discussion

ok, here's the long and short of it. Why was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/how-to-learn-haskell) question not closed?
Yet [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423094/good-resources-for-teaching-a-class-in-python) one was?

It seems to me that the first question was not closed because it was asked a long time ago. So, really, over time, the point system favors those who got here first, especially since any question is more likely to be a duplicate of another question over time (many factors - including the ephemeral nature of technology itself - mitigate this, but my point still stands).
Also, as the site "matures" we get more and more people becoming administrators. This seems like a good idea, and for the most part i agree with the concept. Except that, again, over time there will be more administrators and as the site gains more administrators, the policing becomes more strictly enforced and begins to strangle the vibrant discussions that this community engenders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, nobody reads questions about Haskell except people interested in Haskell, and so nobody flagged. it.

Second, the question is back from Ought Nine, back when questions like this were okay.  That is no longer true today.  But these older questions are, as a general rule, grandfathered in.  They do get locked, closed and deleted (often times at JA's discretion).  This one hasn't yet (I did just wiki it; I don't like closing/deleting old questions, so I leave that to other mods/the community).

Some of these types of questions are viable on programmers.SE.  Some here.  But if the community in general doesn't want it, they can close/delete it.